# What is the use of Double.MAX_VALUE when assigning it to a variable? (Beginner here)

Tags: java, algorithm, integer, double

From my understanding, when assigning a Double.MAX_VALUE to a variable x, then x = 2147483647. My question is, why would you assign such a value to a variable ? And what happens if I remove it from the code below? The code below taken from https://java2blog.com/dijkstra-java/ implements the Dijkstra algorithm in java. It represents the Vertex class.

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
 
public class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex> {
 
 private String name;
 private List<Edge> adjacenciesList;
 private boolean visited;
 private Vertex predecessor;
 private double distance = Double.MAX_VALUE;
 
 public Vertex(String name) {
 this.name = name;
 this.adjacenciesList = new ArrayList<>();
 }
 
 public void addNeighbour(Edge edge) {
 this.adjacenciesList.add(edge);
 }
 
 public String getName() {
 return name;
 }
 
 public void setName(String name) {
 this.name = name;
 }
 
 public List<Edge> getAdjacenciesList() {
 return adjacenciesList;
 }
 
 public void setAdjacenciesList(List<Edge> adjacenciesList) {
 this.adjacenciesList = adjacenciesList;
 }
 
 public boolean isVisited() {
 return visited;
 }
 
 public void setVisited(boolean visited) {
 this.visited = visited;
 }
 
 public Vertex getPredecessor() {
 return predecessor;
 }
 
 public void setPredecessor(Vertex predecessor) {
 this.predecessor = predecessor;
 }
 
 public double getDistance() {
 return distance;
 }
 
 public void setDistance(double distance) {
 this.distance = distance;
 }
 
 @Override
 public String toString() {
 return this.name;
 }
 
 @Override
 public int compareTo(Vertex otherVertex) {
 return Double.compare(this.distance, otherVertex.getDistance());
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because now you can properly compare the value with other values, `if (newDistance < distance) { ... }`

Comment: 2147483647 is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, not `Double.MAX_VALUE`... See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Double.MAX_VALUE).

Answer (score 2):

Since for Dijsktra you search a minimal value (distance), your variable that holds your minimum distance is set to the MAXIMUM_VALUE, since "every other value" is less than that. This guarantees that you will set and compare your first minimum distance properly.

---

*edit*:

> But what if you don't put it as MAX_VALUE? Will you not still be able to compare and set the distance as well?

Since you search for a distance that you do not know, choosing any other value as starting value will introduce a source of errors for the case:

```
starting_value < minimal_distance <= MAXIMUM_VALUE
```

Or to put it in another way: If you search for a maximum value in [0,∞), why do we insist on starting with `0`? Because it's the correct way.

Comment: But what if you don't put it as MAX_VALUE? Will you not still be able to compare and set the distance as well?

Comment: @PhilipNajjar Yes, but if you initialize with 10 the comparisons will be off if the actual minimal distance would be 20, but comparing it with 10 will always let the 10 "win" even though there is not valid path for that distance.